# How to center download button and reduce the size?

Tags: html, css

How to center a button and make it smaller than shown in the image?

HTML:

```
<a href="SUJITBANNE.pdf" download="SUJITBANNE" class="cv">Download CV</a>
```

CSS-

```
.cv {
  position: relative;
  background: #080808;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the image?

Comment: the CSS pretty much explains itself, it's plain English.. and you can Google the style rules, so lets assume you tried to read the CSS, and googled what you did not understand, and still did not manage.. you did not specify to reduce it from what to what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you Go

```css
    .cv {
      position: relative;
      background: #080808;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 10px 30px;
      font-size: 18px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: 500;
      text-align: center;
      width: 30%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="SUJITBANNE.pdf" download="SUJITBANNE" class="cv">Download CV</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the display property to flex and add a new property called justify-content with the value of center. This should work

Comment: Would be nice if you provide more details. Like code example.